# How remove registred,deployed bean

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I use jboss 4.2.2.Ga, EJB , and I have following error:

```
-- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=Name.jar
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container jboss.j2ee:jar=Name.jar,name=SomeBean,service=EJB3,VMID=11d1def534ea1be0:-7f0456b1:1522aa9feea:-7ffd + is already registered

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:service=EJB3,module=Name.jar
  State: FAILED
  Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container jboss.j2ee:jar=name.jar,name=SomeBean,service=EJB3,VMID=11d1def534ea1be0:-7f0456b1:1522aa9feea:-7ffd + is already registered
```

I clear tmp folder after this restart but same problem
any idea how to  fix this problem?
or what is real cause of this

Comment: Can you provide us with the deployment descriptor of Name.jar, and the source code of SomeBean ?

Comment: Did you try cleaning jboss..\standalone\deployments folder ?

Comment: there is no folder like this..

Comment: I kave not deploymentDescriptor , there is no Xml configurations for beans
package samepackage;
`@Remote
public interface Site {

}
package sameackage;
//implementation
@Stateless
public class SiteBean implements Site {

} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have delete /build/classes folder and everything is ok.